# Can't get ol to display label in a list

Tags: html, css

My ordered list is not displaying numbers in latest Chrome or IE 11. I've tried using

```
<ol type="1">
```

and right now I'm trying to style my list:

```
<div class="pagesleftcontent">
  <p>yadda yadda yadda</p>
  <ol>
    <li>yadda yadda yadda</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

using CSS:

```
.pagesleftcontent ol {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
.pagesleftcontent ol li{
    margin-top:5px; 
    text-align:justify;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

To no avail.  Any suggestions?

http://www.jjbrookings.com/ManagedCollections/propaganda.shtml#features/203

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete code example in your question.

Comment: please link relevant code as a snippet or a fiddle not the link to entire site. thanks

Comment: Did any of these solutions work for you? Are you still seeking an answer?

Comment: None of those worked, but I'm not seeking an answer now anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You have this style in your css:

```
.wowbook-page li {
    list-style: outside none none;
}
```

I think you should change this rule to `.wowbook-page ul` or `.wowbook-page ol` , and then the css code you mentioned on the question should fix your issue.

You can add `!important` if wowbook-page rule overwrites your style:

```
.pagesleftcontent ol {
    list-style-type: decimal !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It should work but for some reason it doesn't. I've given up on the ordered list approach for now, but this has been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This works. You don't have to specify `type=1`. That is the default:

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol):

```
TYPE
Indicates the numbering type:
'a' indicates lowercase letters,
'A' indicates uppercase letters,
'i' indicates lowercase Roman numerals,
'I' indicates uppercase Roman numerals,
and '1' indicates numbers (default).``
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>How are you?</li>
</ol>
```